# Array reference expression not completely evaluated

Tags: java, arrays, post-increment

Would you guys kindly enlighten me on the following:

Snippet 1:

```
public class ArrayKoPo {

    public static int[] getArray() {
        return null;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int i = 0;
        try {
            int j = getArray()[i++];
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(i); //prints 1 <---- This one I expected.
        }
    }
}
```

Snippet 2:

```
public class ArrayKoPo {

    public static int[][] getArray() {
        return null;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int i = 0;
        try {
            int j = getArray()[i++][i++];
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(i); //still prints 1 <---- This one I don't understand. I thought 2 will be printed.
        }
    }
}
```

How come the variable i is not incremented twice in the second block of code?

What am I missing?

Thanks.

Comment: `getArray()[i++]` triggers the `NullPointerException`, so it doesn't get to the point of indexing `[i++]` on `getArray()[i++]`. Java evaluates left-to-right :-)

Comment: I see. That's what I missed there. I thought all expressions within the brackets will be evaluated first (left to right) before the whole indexing operation happens, but as you pointed out, the indexing operation happens "index by index" left to right. Thanks for explaining veer! :)

Comment: I have since revamped my answer with ample evidence!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12066481/array-reference-expression-not-completely-evaluated#comment16116833_12066481)...

First, it is important to note that Java evaluates left-to-right. We find that `getArray()[i++]` attempts to access an element of `null` treated as an array, which thus produces a `NullPointerException`. This exception interrupts the evaluation of the expression `getArray()[i++][i++]` before the outer array access expression is evaluated (whose index is computed as `i++`) and thus the second increment never happens :-)

---

This is in conformance with [§15.13 of the Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.13), which describes array access expressions.

> ```
> ArrayAccess:
>     ExpressionName [ Expression ]
>     PrimaryNoNewArray [ Expression ]
> ```

The step-by-step procedure of evaluation of the expression is stated clearly in [§15.13.1 Run-time Evaluation of Array Access](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.13.1):

> An array access expression is evaluated using the following procedure:
>
> - First, the array reference expression is evaluated. If this evaluation completes abruptly, then the array access completes abruptly for the same reason and the index expression is not evaluated.
> - Otherwise, the index expression is evaluated. If this evaluation completes abruptly, then the array access completes abruptly for the same reason.
> - Otherwise, if the value of the array reference expression is `null`, then a `NullPointerException` is thrown.
> - Otherwise, the value of the array reference expression indeed refers to an array. If the value of the index expression is less than zero, or greater than or equal to the array's `length`, then an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` is thrown.
> - Otherwise, the result of the array access is the variable of type T, within the array, selected by the value of the index expression.
>
>   ---

Now, to make sense of our results, you must realize that Java multidimensional arrays are inherently *jagged* and implemented as **arrays of arrays**; an `int[][]` is merely an array of `int[]`.

The true expression at hand involves *two* array access expressions, namely an outer array access expression whose index expression is `i++` and the array reference expression is itself an array access expression, namely one whose reference expression is `getArray()` and whose index expression is `i++`.

Following the rules of evaluation, to evaluate the expression `getArray()[i++][i++]`, we first must evaluate the array reference expression i.e. `getArray()[i++]`. As it turns out, this is itself an array access and expression and we must apply the same rule. Evaluating `getArray()` results in `null`. The index expression `i++` also completes fully (incrementing `i`), before reaching the step in which a `NullPointerException` is thrown at this point. Since the outer array access expression's array reference expression ended abruptly, so too does it and thus the outer access expression's index expression (`i++`) is not evaluated, meaning `i` is only incremented once.

... and now you know ;-)

Answer (score 3):

I believe it happens like the following:

1. The program runs to the point where it getArray(): a null is returned.
2. Then the program moves on to the square brackets, evaluates the argument, and tries go into the array. (Java magic that I am unfamiliar with happens here)
3. The try fails and a exceptions is generated **before** the second index operator is looked at.

If we would to put your second snippet in another way, it should be equivalent to the following (and thus generating the same result as the first snippet):

```
public class ArrayKoPo {

    public static int[][] getArray() {
        return null;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int i = 0;
        try {
            int[] j = getArray()[i++];
            int k = j[i++];
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: great example which helps to understand how it works!